# Browser flickering when using invalidateLater()

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm making an interactive dashboard with R & Shiny. One graphical object is a kind of plot that automatically updates 10 times per second:

```
output$graph <- renderPlot({
    draw.graph(data)        
    invalidateLater(100, session) 
})
```

It is functional, and runs smoothly when started locally (on Firefox, can't test Internet Explorer as this doesn't give graphics when running Shiny locally).

However once hosted on Shiny server (On Linux Mint which runs in VMware on a Windows 7 machine, but I don't think that's crucial) that graph flickers:

- Firefox and Chrome: nearly acceptable; about one 'flash' every few seconds.
- Internet Explorer 9: 'flashes' every frame (so 10 times a second!).

The 'flashes' look like the graph goes totally white before switching to the updated graph (while it is supposed to look like an animation).

Possibly related: I've found out Internet Explorer is saving all versions of the graph in Temporary Internet Files. One frame is only 50Kb, but at 10 a second this adds up. This doesn't explains why it goes white shortly between frames, but if I could somehow prevent IE from saving it would at least run somewhat better.

Not offering the application in for IE9 is not an option for the users.

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: With `renderPlot` you will be repainting everything every 0.1 seconds, My advice is to use some `javascript` libraries which would have asynchronous callbacks built in so you can only paint the most recent updates (if they changed). Make sure you only paint the most recent updates. Also why are you doing this every 0.1 seconds?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm afraid asynchronous callbacks are not going to make a difference in the flickering.

The image changes with every frame anyway. The 0.1 seconds is to make it look like a smooth movement. I tried 0.2 but that's notably less.

Comment: Why do you need such a quick response? What are you doing? Normally 1 second refresh is enough

Comment: Imagine watching a movie at one frame per second.

Comment: are you rendering movies? I don't think `renderPlot` will suffice